# In WPF, How can I use different style of series in one cartesian chart?

Tags: wpf, livecharts

For information, I'm using Live charts library.

What I want to make is a chart column chart with reference information.
The result is going to be like below.

[image]
What I planned to do is using column chart and step line chart.
And when I run, the result is only showing column charts. 
Even Step line series data is also shown as column.

How can I show different styles in one chart?

[image]

This is my Xaml Code.

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="1200" >
        <lvc:CartesianChart Name="MainChart" Series="{Binding Path=MainData}" Width="{Binding Path=MainChartWidth}">
                <lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
                    <lvc:DefaultTooltip SelectionMode="OnlySender"/>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:Axis Name="XAxis" Labels="{Binding Path=MainDataLabel}" ></lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>            
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And this is code behind related to question.

```
        for (int idx = 0; idx < MainDataTable.Columns.Count; idx++)
        {
            List<string[]> tmpList = new List<string[]>();

            else if (idx == 1)
            {
                string[] tmpArray = new string[3];

                StepLineSeries tmpLineSeries = new StepLineSeries();
                List<int> tmpDataList = new List<int>();
                tmpLineSeries.Title = MainDataTable.Columns[idx].ColumnName;
                tmpLineSeries.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                tmpLineSeries.PointGeometry = null;
                tmpLineSeries.Width = 10;
                tmpLineSeries.StrokeThickness = 10;


                for (int rowCnt = 0; rowCnt < MainDataTable.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
                {
                    tmpDataList.Add(Int32.Parse(MainDataTable.Rows[rowCnt][idx].ToString()));
                }
                tmpLineSeries.Values = new ChartValues<int>(tmpDataList);

                MainData.Add(tmpLineSeries);

            }
            else if (idx > 1) // (idx > 0)
            {
                string[] tmpArray = new string[3];

                ColumnSeries tmpLineSeries = new ColumnSeries();
                List<int> tmpDataList = new List<int>();
                tmpLineSeries.Title = MainDataTable.Columns[idx].ColumnName;
                tmpLineSeries.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(searchCondition.getConditionColor(MainDataTable.Columns[idx].ColumnName));
                tmpLineSeries.Width = 15;

                for (int rowCnt = 0; rowCnt < MainDataTable.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
                {
                    tmpDataList.Add(Int32.Parse(MainDataTable.Rows[rowCnt][idx].ToString()));
                }
                tmpLineSeries.Values = new ChartValues<int>(tmpDataList);

                MainData.Add(tmpLineSeries);

            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You’re definitely on the right track. From your code I can’t tell why your StepLineSeries should appear as a column (I’m guessing it’s the red column). What’s the value of `MainDataTable.Columns.Count`?

One other thing you might want to do is use a ScatterSeries instead, because a StepLineSeries will always generate a connected path. You can make the vertical lines transparent, but the horizontals will never have padding like in your example, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you. I've added xaml needed series and linked each data to solve temporarily. But I'll dig into again and report when there is a answer.